# can you pass in any pointer type or base class into a function typedef

Tags: c++, std, typedef, std-function

I have this code

```
class ClassX {};

class ClassY : public ClassX {};
typedef std::function<void (ClassX*)> myCaller;

class Foo {
    Foo()
    {
        createCaller(this, &Foo::bar); //line 22 with the error
    }

    template <typename Class>
    void createCaller(Class *obj, void (Class::*func)(ClassX*))
    {
         myCaller mc = std::bind(func, obj, std::placeholders::_1);;
    }

    void bar(ClassY* x)
    {
        printf("fooBrr");
    }

};
```

and it works fine till bar takes ClassY that extends ClassX instead of ClassX.

i get the compile time error:
main.cpp:22:9: No matching member function for call to 'createCaller'

The question is how would i go about allowing bar to take a parameter of any class that extends ClassX or any class at all? is it even possible?

Comment: Show us your inheritance hierarchy and the exact error you're receiving.

Comment: Yes. look at `mc` - by definition, it has to be a function object, that accepts a `ClassX*`. But `bar` accepts only `ClassY*` - so mc cannot delegate every possible argument to `bar`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do it because `bar` is more restrictive than `myCaller`.  You can go the other way however:

```
class ClassX {};

class ClassY : public ClassX {};
typedef std::function<void (ClassY*)> myCaller;

class Foo {
    Foo()
    {
        createCaller(this, &Foo::bar); //line 22 with the error
    }

    template <typename Class>
    void createCaller(Class *obj, void (Class::*func)(ClassX*))
    {
         myCaller mc = std::bind(func, obj, std::placeholders::_1);
    }

    void bar(ClassX* x)
    {
        printf("fooBrr");
    }

};
```

Now `bar` is less restrictive than `myCaller` so it can be bound.

You can also have `bar` take a `ClassX*` and dynamic_cast it to a `ClassY*` and check for NULL.

Comment: ya i have been dynamic casting but was hoping for some new fancy c++ 11 feature that makes it possible. Guess not. Thx :)

Answer (score 1):

For ClassY and other derived classes it is possible, easily:

```
#include <functional>

class ClassX {};

class ClassY : public ClassX {};

typedef std::function<void (ClassX*)> myCaller;

int main()
{
    myCaller f = [](ClassX*){};
    ClassY classY;
    f(&classY);
}
```

You have to keep some things in mind, though:

- You pass an address of a ClassY object, not a ClassY object itself. You said you would pass a ClassY, which is wrong.
- You declare the parameter to be `ClassX*`, so may not pass a poitner to const (i.e. `const ClassY*` is forbidden)
- The compiler has to *know* that ClassY is derived from ClassX, so you have to include the definition (header) of ClassY.
- The code where you call the function must have access to the "is derived" property, so ClassY should derive *public* from ClassX (For nitpickers: yes, there's `protected`, and there's `friend` and of course the inheritance can be indirect through multiple levels of inheritance...)

But all of these don't apply only to `std::function`, but to functions in general.
For any other class that does not (visible and accessible) derive from ClassX, you can't call the function.

Comment: added a bit more detail to try and clarify my problem